# Intel Pin : Why are RTN level analysis calls' Thread ID argument always zero?

Tags: c++, intel

I am writing a profiler using **Intel Pin**. The tool profiles functions in an executable by adding instrumentation code before and after each routine. For each routine, I add callbacks in Pin as below

```
RTN_InsertCall(routine, IPOINT_BEFORE, (AFUNPTR)BeforeCall,
    IARG_UINT32, RTN_Id(routine),
    IARG_THREAD_ID,
    IARG_END);

RTN_InsertCall(routine, IPOINT_AFTER, (AFUNPTR)AfterCall,
    IARG_UINT32, RTN_Id(routine),
    IARG_THREAD_ID,
    IARG_END);
```

The BeforeCall and AfterCall look like

```
VOID BeforeCall(unsigned int funcID,THREADID threadID);
VOID AfterCall(unsigned int funcID,THREADID threadID);
```

The '**threadID**' variable in these callbacks always has a **value of zero**. The application being instrumented has **32 threads** running. The examples shipped with Pin use the same method for accessing the thread ID. Is this implementation right? If not, how do I get hold of the actual thread ID of the thread the routine is running on?

Answer (score 0):

If you look in the Intel manual, it tells you about what is necessary for instrumenting multi-threaded programs. There are several ways to retrieve the threadid---the one that works for me is using

```
 PIN_GetThreadID()
```

in the analysis routine. But there are cases where it is more optimal to use that argument; I'm not sure if you're trying to use the manual or not, but [here](http://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/pintool/docs/61206/Pin/html/index.html#MallocMT) is a good example of a multi-threaded target that uses *Image based instrumentation to insert RTN level calls*. By contrast, I don't know exactly what yours is.

Additionally, while you mention that the example intel ships with uses this method, you haven't said much about the contrast between your results and the intel provided pintool. Why not try and run their tool against your target to see if it works, and post your results? Also, if it does work, what about the route of modifing their tool to incorporate your code?

Additionally, there is a subtle error plaguing your pintool; since you haven't read the manual all the way through, it seems that you are using RTN level instrumentation believing that you will be able to gather all returns from a given call. What you should know in this situation is that the compiler does a lot of optimization, and while it may be generally guaranteed that you can capture all calls, instrumenting all returns isn't guaranteed because a function can have multiple returns. For this, you should use Trace based instrumentation (also described in the manual).

If you find that this doesn't answer your question, I think it is more fitting that you post your source. Hopefully, it's better that you could set up a github repo that I can just pull that will immediately work for me-small and reproducible with little effort to configure. For that I recommend using the out of folder makefile.